# Function of って in this sentence

Tags: meaning, quotes, particle-って

> 俺のことは、みんなと同じように親父とでも呼んでくれや。親父のように強くたくましく頼りになる**って**な。

Is the speaker quoting what other people have said about him?

Comment: While this second sentence sounds a little strange to me (and I speak 関西弁), I'm getting the feeling that he's either saying something along the lines of 親父のように強く逞しく頼りになれるからな or 親父のように強く逞しく頼りになる、なんてな. I apologize that I can't give an explanation as to why I feel this way, but maybe it will help you. Hopefully someone else will have better insight.

Comment: ^ It doesn't sound strange to me (and I'm a 関西弁 native, too). It doesn't mean 頼りになれるからな or 頼りになる、なんてな. 「『強くて、たくましくて、頼りになる。』と(思って/考えて/いう意味で、親父と呼んでくれ)。」って意味よ～　(btw「頼りにな**れ**る」とは言わないですね)

Comment: あくまで個人の感想として述べてんけど、自分からしたら若干自虐的に見えるんですよねぇ・・・(少なくとも「なんて」としての解釈に関しては)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「俺{おれ}のことは、みんなと同{おな}じように親父{おやじ}とでも呼{よ}んでくれや。親父のように強{つよ}くたくましく頼{たよ}りになるってな。」
>
> Is the speaker quoting what other people have said about him?

From only the two sentences provided, one could not know for certain whether others have actually said to the speaker「You are 親父のように強くたくましく頼りになる。」.

All that can be safely concluded is that the speaker would like the listener(s) to ***feel*** that he is 親父のように強くたくましく頼りになる.

That is because the quotative particles 「と」 and 「って」 are often used to talk about what one feels, thinks, believes, etc.  They are not used exclusively for what one states using actual words.

> "Just call me like 'Dad' as everyone does, okay? I want you to feel that I am strong and dependable like your (real) Dad."